# iPhone zoomed in on page when opened

Tags: iphone, zooming, viewport

I've been working on my first responsive design, and I'm having some trouble when viewing it on my iPhone. When I open a page on the iPhone, it's a little zoomed in to the left – just enough to miss text on the far right.

You can find the website [here](http://www.andersnoren.se). The viewport-meta tag looks like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;" />
```

It looks fine on my computer and on my iPad. Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. I had put `width:100%;` and `padding:0 10px;` on the .wrapper element under `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)`. Changed it to `width:96%` and `padding: 0 2%;`, and it worked like a charm.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It might have worked for you, but have you tested how it looks on different devices? Android, Windows phone, small screens? Making the content fit the zoom I think is not solving te problem at all.

Answer (score 14):

Try this viewport, it works great on my website:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: Didn't work, unfortunately. Probably something in the CSS, then?

Comment: Most likely. You probably have some content that is sticking out of the page.

Comment: Just had a look at your site from my iPhone. It's definitely css. Make sure you don't have any fixed values for width, but rather %.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `width:100%; overflow:hidden;` to both `body` and `html` elements. If your page load differently, its definitely a css issue.

Answer (score 1):

See if you are using `100vh` in your CSS anywhere. If you are using `100vh` it counts the menu bar and bottom toolbar as part of the `100vh`. See https://chanind.github.io/javascript/2019/09/28/avoid-100vh-on-mobile-web.html